# Does apt 1.0 supports search patterns like aptitude?

Tags: 14.04, apt, aptitude

`aptitude search ~ipackage` will search for installed `package` only. Can apt 1.0 (i.e. standalone apt, not apt-cache, dpkg or any else) do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt list "*linux*" --installed
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page `man apt` *(run this to view other options)*:

```
   search
       search searches for the given term(s) and display matching
       packages.
```

So `apt search PACKAGE` will work - e.g. for `firefox`:
[image: apt search firefox output]

**See also:**

- http://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/

Comment: apt search return huge list sometimes. I want list that contains installed packages only.